# MVC 5 Razor code-first EF Junction Table with IdentityUser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

So I've got these 2 class and User coming from individual user accounts

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }      
    public virtual ICollection<Basket> Baskets { get; set; }     
}

public class Basket
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Key]
    public int BasketId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Words { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

EF has created UserBaskets with 2 FK. I have items in my Basket class that I seeded.

My question is, how can I add row to my junction table in the controller? For example, a logged user click on a basket and return the Id...Now I've got

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Basket(int? basketid)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var job = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            job.Baskets.Add(basketid);
            db.Users.Add(job);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Basket");
        }

        return View(db.Baskets.ToList());
    }
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally chose to add a junction table manually

```
public class UserBasket
{
    [Key]
    public int UserBasketId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public virtual Basket Basket { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

and could add a row using identityUser like this

```
UserManager<User> userManager = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(db));
var user = userManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
Basket basket = db.Basket.Find(id);
var userbasket = new UserBasket {User = user, Basket = basket, Date = DateTime.Now };
db.UserBasket.Add(userbasket);
db.SaveChanges();
```